# Existence of Spanning Tree implies Well Ordering Principle

Tags: graph-theory, axiom-of-choice

1. Every connected graph has a spanning tree.
2. Every non-empty set can be well ordered.

Basically I am trying to show that statement 1 implies statement 2. What I tried is as following:
Let $X \ne \emptyset$, define a graph $G$ with $$V(G) := \{v_{S}:S \subseteq X\}$$ and $v_S v_T \in E(G)$ if and only if either $S \subseteq T$ and $|T| = |S| + 1$ or vice versa. By statement 1, there is a spanning tree so we choose the path (possibly infinite) that connects $v_{\emptyset}$ and $V_X$, and define a total order $\le$ on $X$ by the order each element $x \in X$ is added in the path that connects $v_{\emptyset}$ and $v_X$.

I talked to a professor about this, apparently connected means each pair of vertices is connected by a **FINITE** path, so my proof is technically wrong, but I think that's the general direction to proceed. Any hint on actually proving it?

Comment: This is a good question, just not for this site - you should ask it at math.stackexchange.

Comment: As the well-ordering principle is equivalent to the axiom of choice, forget about well-ordering and just prove directly that (1) implies AC. Let $A_i,i\in I$ be a given family of nonempty sets. Let $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$. Assume w.l.o.g. that $I\cap A=\emptyset.$ Let $G=(V,E)$ where $V=I\cup A$ and $$E=\{\{u,v\}:u,v\in A,u\ne v\}\cup\{\{i,v\}:i\in I,v\in A_i\}.$$Let $T$ be a spanning tree for this connected graph. Choose $a\in A.$ For each $i\in I$ the tree $T$ contains a unique path $P_i$ from $i$ to $a,$ and $P_i$ contains a unique edge $\{i,v_i\}$ where $v_i\in A_i.$

Comment: Note also that a *well-order* is very different from a *total order*. I do not know whether "every set can be totally ordered implies the axiom of choice.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It's all over my head but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension#Order-extension_principle) says that the ordering principle is weaker than the order-extension principle, which is weaker than the Boolean prime ideal theorem, which is weaker than the axiom of choice.

Comment: See [theorem 2](https://www.renyi.hu/pub/setop/otka61600/infinite.pdf).

Comment: I think the question is on-topic for MO, and that @bof's comment should be an answer. I have voted to re-open.

Comment: @bof I agree with your construction, in fact, i believe using existence of spanning tree to prove axiom of choice directly is standard question in infinite graphs. I am curious about whether or not there is a direct way of proving well-ordering without having to prove axiom of choice.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, I should have mentioned that I have the proof for that implication. Thanks for voting to reopen though. (:

Comment: @GuoXianYau It seems unlikely that a spanning tree will be directly useful in a proof of the well-ordering theorem. The graph you suggested in the question has an obvious spanning tree, no choice needed: the "star graph" in which each vertex $v_S (\emptyset\ne S\subseteq X)$ is joined by an edge to $v_\emptyset.$ This tree is not going to help you well-order $X.$

Comment: @bof In my construction not all edges are in the graph, for example, $v_{\emptyset}$ and $v_{\{x,y\}}$ does not have an edge joining them.

Anyway, thanks for the help, proving well-ordering principle directly from spanning tree has been puzzling me for a while, at least I was wondering if it is even possible to prove it directly.

Comment: @GuoXianYau Oh, right, I overlooked that. It seems that your graph is not connected if $X$ is an infinite set; there is no edge joining a vertex in $\{v_S:S\text{ is finite}\}$ to a vertex in $\{v_S:S\text{ is infinite}\}.$ Since the graph is not connected, statement 1 does not apply.

Comment: @bof Yea, when I started constructing the graph I've overlook that as well. Somehow I feel that some modification should be able to prove the well-ordering principle but I have not succeeded so far.

Comment: @bof Oh wow, didn't realise you can do that. Brilliant proof for that implication! (:

Comment: @NoahSchweber You can use the compactness theorem to show that every set can be totally ordered, and the compactness theorem requires only the ultrafilter principle (i.e., BPIT). You probably don't need it, but other readers who are curious can read this: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactness+theorem#totalorder

Comment: @ToddTrimble Ah, yes, I should have seen that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let AC denote the axiom of choice. The proof of the implication AC $\implies$ (2) is somewhat nontrivial. Inasmuch as the equivalence AC $\iff$ (1) is quite trivial, it seems unlikely that any "direct" proof of the implication (1) $\implies$ (2) will be much simpler than (1) $\implies$ AC $\implies$ (2). The rest of this answer is devoted to exhibiting simple proofs of AC $\implies$ (1) and (1) $\implies$ AC.

**AC $\implies$ (1):** Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected graph. Choose a vertex $r\in V.$ For each vertex $v\in V\setminus\{r\},$ choose a vertex $v'\in V$ such that $v'$ is adjacent to $v$ and $d(v',r)\lt d(v,r).$ The set of all edges $\{v,v'\}$ is a spanning tree.

**(1) $\implies$ AC:** Let $A_i (i\in I)$ be a family of nonempty sets, and let $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i.$ We may assume that $I\cap A=\emptyset.$ Consider the connected graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=I\cup A$ and
$$E=\{\{u,v\}:u,v\in A,u\ne v\}\cup\{\{i,v\}:i\in I,v\in A_i\}.$$
Let $T$ be a spanning tree for $G$. Choose a vertex $r\in A.$ For each $i\in I$ the tree $T$ contains a unique path $P_i$ from $i$ to $r,$ and $P_i$ contains a unique edge $\{i,a_i\}$ where $a_i\in A_i.$ Now $i\mapsto a_i$ is a choice function for the family $A_i (i\in I).$

Comment: I would agree as that is what I did basically. Will accept this as answer for now until someone actually showed a proof of statement 1 implies statement 2 without using other equivalent formulations of axiom of choice. Cheers! (: